# Mongoid - Getting Date instead of Time when serializing DateTime field in JSON API response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, datetime, mongoid

I'm writing a Rails app to act as a web service only for a mobile app. I created it using the `--api` and `--skip-active-record` switches. My model has a DateTime field.

Here is the code for my Model and the method I was calling in my Controller. Because I'm using `--api`, there is no View code:

```
class GroceryItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :expiry, type: Date
end

# grocery_items_controller.rb
# GET /grocery_items/1
def show
  render json: @grocery_item
end
```

In the database, I can see that the time component of that field is being stored:

```
db.grocery_items.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58a9298da1c1d12e7cee02d9"), "name" : "Chocolate", "expiry" : ISODate("2017-02-19T05:13:49.253Z") }
```

I can also see this in the Rails console:

```
irb(main):003:0> GroceryItem.first
=> #<GroceryItem _id: 58a9298da1c1d12e7cee02d9, name: "Chocolate", expiry: 2017-02-19 05:13:49 UTC>
```

However, when I try to access the expiry using the method on my GroceryItem model class, I get a Date object. I only get the date portion of the data, not the time portion:

```
irb(main):004:0> GroceryItem.first.expiry
=> Sun, 19 Feb 2017

irb(main):005:0> GroceryItem.first.expiry.class
=> Date

irb(main):006:0> GroceryItem.first.expiry.to_s
=> "2017-02-19"
```

Calling `to_json` and `as_json` on the instance also omit the data:

```
irb(main):008:0> GroceryItem.first.to_json
=> "{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"58a9298da1c1d12e7cee02d9\"},\"expiry\":\"2017-02-19\",\"name\":\"Chocolate\"}"

irb(main):009:0> GroceryItem.first.as_json
=> {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('58a9298da1c1d12e7cee02d9'), "expiry"=>Sun, 19 Feb 2017, "name"=>"Chocolate"}
```

Which leads to my JSON response omiting the data. I'm assuming the rendering process in the controller uses either `to_json` or `as_json` to do the rendering:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58a9298da1c1d12e7cee02d9"
    },
    "expiry": "2017-02-19",
    "name": "Chocolate"
}
```

I was finally able to figure out how to access this data by calling the following. You can see how I finally get the Time Ruby class:

```
irb(main):010:0> GroceryItem.first.attributes[:expiry]
=> 2017-02-19 05:13:49 UTC

irb(main):011:0> GroceryItem.first.attributes[:expiry].class
=> Time
```

Which allows me to finally have a way of serializing the data in a way compatible with the ISO8601 specification to match the data stored in MongoDB:

```
irb(main):012:0> GroceryItem.first.attributes[:expiry].utc.iso8601
=> "2017-02-19T05:13:49Z"
```

Surely this behaviour isn't correct. When a developer chooses the DataTime  type for a field, they must want the time component to come through. Otherwise, they would use the Date type instead. I understand now that I could override the default Rails API and Mongoid pairing behaviour by creating a view to render the JSON in a way I see fit, but I was considering filing a bug report because I feel like the default behaviour should be changed to automatically render all of the data stored in the database when a developer chooses the DateTime field type.

I was wondering if anybody here has any input on this issue before I proceed with filing a bug report.

Comment: ```GroceryItem.first.attributes[:expiry].class``` => Time ? The type is Date, why do I get a Time here? Can somebody please help?

Comment: @Ekkstein You should create your own question on Stack Overflow for your problem. The accepted answer here is from 2017, so things may have changed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue seems to be in your code:

```
class GroceryItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :expiry, type: Date
end
```

Here, **expiry has type of Date**, so it is expected to return a Date without time component. I think using the appropriate type will solve your problem.

Comment: I actually just found this out after more experimentation. I noticed that when I tried again to create an app and generate the scaffold (```rails g scaffold grocery_item name expiry:datetime```) it worked. It made my model's type ```Time``` this time. I can't believe I didn't catch that, I feel like I used ```expiry:datetime``` the first time.

I'm still glad it's working by default. :)

Comment: @Welkie Haha, no worries, happens :) not so fast "filing a bug report" :D

Comment: This is why I always take the opportunity to get humiliated on StackOverflow first. :D Slightly less embarrassing.

Comment: @Welkie - Oh no, nothing to embarrass, just chill.